# Loading csv with thousands of columns into pandas and with correct data types

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, dummy-variable

The csv I'm loading into jupyter notebook with pandas has over 4,000 columns and about half are dummy variable columns with the following values: 0, 1, ' '.
Because of the ' ' values, pandas creates these columns with data type "object" instead of "int". This is causing issues because I need to run regressions on these columns and don't want to go through one by one changing their data types.
How do I get pandas to load these columns with the data type "int" during the initial pd.read_csv command?

Comment: If you want them to be ints, what should `''` be in those columns?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your csv?